# SQL Query help: Employee "Cat_Code" change with "Eff_Date"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have data following format and want  "Cat_Code" change with "Eff_Date" column.

Data is order by "Emp_ID" and "Eff_Date" and "Cat_Code" is string value "Eff_Date" , "Date_Updated" is date only.
Can anyone help me to how to write the query? Thanks in advance.

**Table Data:**

```
**Emp_ID        Eff_Date    Cat_Code    Date_Updated    User_ID**
100021      27/12/2015      030     28/12/2015      FER
100021      27/12/2015      030     07/01/2016      AZI
100021      16/04/2016      030     17/04/2016      FER
100021      01/11/2016      030     13/11/2016      FER
100021      01/02/2019      030     23/02/2019      AZI
100021      01/08/2019      021     25/08/2019      IK

100054      05/09/2014      030     07/09/2014      FER
100054      01/12/2014      030     21/12/2014      WAL
100054      28/04/2015      030     28/04/2015      IK
100054      01/05/2015      030     17/05/2015      WAL
100054      01/05/2016      030     15/05/2016      AZI
100054      13/07/2018      030     11/08/2018      AZI
100054      01/11/2018      030     12/12/2018      AJA
100054      01/01/2019      030     17/01/2019      MMAC
100054      01/08/2019      021     25/08/2019      IK

100086      01/09/2015      030     15/09/2015      FER
100086      01/09/2015      030     16/09/2015      AJA
100086      01/09/2015      030     30/09/2015      MRA
100086      16/09/2015      030     16/09/2015      AJA
100086      01/11/2015      030     19/11/2015      AZI
100086      28/08/2016      030     28/08/2016      FER
100086      01/11/2016      030     15/11/2016      FER
100086      01/10/2017      030     30/09/2017      FER
100086      01/11/2017      048     16/07/2019      GPA
100086      01/11/2017      030     12/11/2017      AJA
100086      01/11/2017      048     22/01/2018      FER
100086      10/03/2018      048     26/03/2018      FER
100086      01/06/2018      048     07/08/2018      AZI
100086      01/04/2019      048     27/04/2019      AZI
100086      01/07/2019      030     13/07/2019      GPA
100086      01/07/2019      030     16/07/2019      GPA
```

**Expected result:**

```
**Emp_ID        Eff_Date    Cat_Code    Date_Updated    User_ID**
100021      27/12/2015      030     28/12/2015      FER
100021      01/08/2019      021     25/08/2019      IK

100054      05/09/2014      030     07/09/2014      FER
100054      01/08/2019      021     25/08/2019      IK

100086      01/09/2015      030     15/09/2015      FER
100086      01/11/2017      048     22/01/2018      FER
100086      01/07/2019      030     13/07/2019      GPA
```

Comment: You've given use example data and an expected result (good), but not explained what criteria determines the data shown in your expected result, and it's not obvious just from looking at it. Can you explain further?

Comment: @IqbalKan - Your new question is still highly ambiguous. Please explain in detail how your business logic is supposed to work. How did you reach that 100086 with cat_code 048 should get that particular value for output? Why are there 2 output rows for 100086, cat_code 030?

Comment: Criteria are that when employee "Cat_Code" and "Eff_Date" changed then print the changed row

Comment: @IqbalKhan - And this only applies for the very first date? Because otherwise, you are missing Emp_ID 100054 - 01/05/2015 - 030. You need to be able to explain the exact behavior you are looking for, because otherwise it will be impossible for anyone to assist you properly. If you are unclear about the behavior, you'll need to find someone to define it for you.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - Sorry for that, Emp_ID was wrong and it corrected. I posted 100086 instead of 100021. I'm stuck with my management requirement, they want data like If an employee "Cat_Code" and "Eff_Date" changed then print the changed row.
Could you please guide?

Comment: @IqbalKhan - So just to summarize what we know so far. Whenever there is an update to an EmpID, you want to list the original version of the data. Is that correct? 

What would you want to show in case you only have the original row, but nothing has changed (yet)? Because if you just want to see that row, too, what your requirement really boils down to is displaying the earliest example of any combination of `EmpID` and `Eff_Date`, right?

Comment: and another duplicate on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4065bf9c-3137-4569-b144-191de8026825/employee-8220catcode8221-change-with-8220effdate8221?forum=ssdt)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't afford enough details about your issue but your query can be something like this:

```
 WITH cte AS (
SELECT Emp_ID
    ,Eff_Date
    ,Cat_Code
    ,isnull(lag(Cat_Code) OVER (
            PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY Eff_Date
            ), '-1') last_CatCode
    ,Date_Updated
    ,User_ID
FROM yourtable
)

    SELECT
        *
    FROM cte
    WHERE Cat_Code != last_CatCode;
```

**UPDATE :**

```
SELECT  Emd_ID, 
    Cat_Code, 
    User_ID,
    MIN(Eff_Date) AS Min_Eff_Date,MAX(Date_Updated) AS Max_Date_Updated
FROM    yourTable
GROUP BY Emd_ID, 
    Cat_Code, 
    User_ID;
```

Comment: I tried this way but not working, It gives all data not the expected result data

Comment: @IqbalKhan can you please share the table structure ?

Comment: [Emp_ID] [float] NOT NULL,
[Eff_Date] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[Cat_Code] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
[USER_ID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Date_Updated] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,

Comment: @IqbalKhan can you add it in your question ?

Comment: WITH CTE AS (select Emp_ID, Eff_Date, Cat_Code, User_ID, Date_Updated,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cat_Code, Eff_Date ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC) rn
        FROM [PRODUCTION].[F123v119] t
        where Emp_ID=102586
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE
    WHERE rn = 1;